# how to nest a php variable in string

Tags: php, html, web

I want to use this variable:

```
$id= $row['property_id'];
```

Inside this href after the equals sign after 'id'

```
echo "<td>""<a href='product_description.php?id='>" . $row['PropertyType'] . "</a></td>";
```

How can I do this? I think it may be a problem with escaping quotes but I can't seem to find a solution. 
I'm new to php and would appreciate the help

Comment: have you tried it just exactly the way you did with `$row['PropertyType']`?

Comment: This would also work for you---
"<td><a href='product_description.php?id=$id'> $row['PropertyType']</a></td>";

Comment: Why don't you simply use `echo "<td><a href='product_description.php?id={$row['property_id']}'>{$row['PropertyType']}</a></td>";` ?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
echo '<td><a href="product_description.php?id=' . $id . '" >' . $row['PropertyType'] . '</a></td>';
```

You should also think about echoing the data in the html, instead of echoing out html itself. It is a lot cleaner.

e.g. you can do the above like this:

```
<?php
   // your php, ready up the data. your $id and $row
?> <!-- close your php tag -->
<td>
   <a href="product_description.php?id=<?= $id ?>" >
      <?= $row['PropertyType'] ?>
   </a>
</td>
```

Note: that `<?= $var ?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo $var ?>`.

Comment: This is a relatively expensive way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to put your variable same as PropertyType which you wrote.
Please find below syntex:

```
echo "<td><a href='product_description.php?id=" . $id . "'>" . $row['PropertyType'] . "</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this ([variable variables](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)):

```
$var_id = 'id';
$$var_id = 'something';

print_r($id);
print_r($var_id);
```

Will give you

```
something
id
```

in output respectively. 
So you can use it like:

```
$var_id = $row['property_id'];
$$var_id = 'id';

echo '<td><a href="product_description.php?'.$var_id.'='.$id.'">'.$id.'</a></td>';
```

That will generate a link that leads to:

```
http://example.com/product_description.php?id=property_id
```

Or simply

```
$id= $row['property_id'];
echo '<td><a href="product_description.php?id='.$id.'">'.$id.'</a></td>';
```